# Add space in adb command

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I want to execute "adb" command using Java.
I tried out as follow:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/c","adb devices"});
```

But, I get following error `p.getErrorStream()`:

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any problem of space between "adb devices"?

How to add space in command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the space, but the fact that `adb` is not found (because it's not on the path).

Do one of those two things:

- make sure that the command is executed at the place where `adb.exe` resides *or*
- modify `PATH` (for that command) in a way that  `adb.exe` is in a directory mentioned in `PATH`.

While both of those are possible with [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29), I'd suggest using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), because it has a much nicer/easier API.

For example to modify the path where the command is executed do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","adb devices");
pb.directory(new File("c:\\path\\to\\android\\platform-tools\\");
pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably problem is in your %PATH% ( or lack thereof )  - it seems that it separated arguments  properly. YO may try to use absolute path to adb executable