# what are the other ways to run downloaded apk on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

**I have downloaded an apk and i want to run it on emulator but i don't know how to run i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator) link**

but i didnt work i get this error on cmd

" 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814103/add-space-in-adb-command

Comment: arash this tutorial i need to make a new java file in eclipse to run it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Past apk file inside android-sdk\tools or platform-tools
2. Go through
   platform-tools in console
3. Then type this command 
   `adb install yourapk.apk`

Comment: android-sdk\tools by this you mean folder inside or outside my eclipse folder coz i dont have this on my eclispe folder

Comment: i was able to install but i didnt run

Comment: go to the installed apps list in your android emulator and look for the icon of your app, and launch it,

Answer (score 0):

```
Steps by steps
1. open your cmd command
2. go to directory where c:\eclipse\adt\sdk\platform-tools
3.befor this u just goto platform-tools folder and paste your apk file
4.after that u just write c:\eclipse\adt\sdk\platform-tools\adb install apk file name
```